# How do I represent one to many in Grails, with a constraint on another domain class?

Tags: grails, constraints

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here's an example.

```
class Album {
   static hasMany = [ reviews: Review ]
}

class Author {
   static hasMany = [ reviews: Review ]
}

class Review {
   static belongsTo = [ album: Album, author: Author ]
}
```

A person can write multiple reviews for multiple albums, but I want to limit them to be able to only write a single review per album.  I've been trying to think of a way to do that with the constraints property, but haven't been able to come up with anything yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a unique constraint

```
class Review {
   static belongsTo = [ album: Album, author: Author ]

   static constraints = {
       album unique: 'author'
   }
}
```

The error code that will be resolved when this constraint is violated is `review.album.unique`

Comment: Doh! Makes my way look pretty complex :) Vote for Don, his way is much nicer!

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that an instance of the `Author` class is the author of a review of an album, in other words the "reviewer".  If so the following validator in the `Review` class will make sure he author has not already reviewed the album.  See http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html for more info on custom validators.

```
class Album {
    static hasMany = [ reviews: Review ]
}

class Author {
    static hasMany = [ reviews: Review ]
}

class Review {
    static belongsTo = [ album: Album, author: Author ]

    static constraints = {
        author(validator: {
            val, obj ->
            for(review in obj.album.reviews){
                if(review.author == val){
                    return 'doubleEntry' //Corresponds to the "review.author.doubleEntry" error in your message.properties file which you will need to create by adding the line "review.author.doubleEntry=You cannot review this Album twice!" to your message.properties file.
                }
            }
            return true
        })
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can enforce it with a constraint unless you can get something like the multiple column unique constraint to work on Review class. So, the unique constraint will be the album and author properties grouped together on the Review class.

I haven't tried it, just saw it in the documentation here: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.RC1/ref/Constraints/unique.html